# How to understand slicing function in python?

Tags: python, slice

I am unable to understand how the statement below gets this answer?
Question:

```
>>>a=[1,2,3,4,5]

>>>a[3:1]
>>>[]

>>>a[3:1:-1]
>>>[4, 3]
```

Please explain to me why did I get this output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: `[start:stop:step]` - similar to `range`... With your second example, the default `step` is 1, so you can't have any items - 1 (your stop) is lower than 3...